# Opaque navigation bar has black view behind it

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I'm manually hiding the navigation bar based on the scroll offset of the scrollview and it works 100% fine with a translucent navbar. However, if it's opaque (I need it to be to get the background colour correct), it produces this black bar which I can't seem to get to go away.

[image: Error]

Comment: "Manually hiding"? Do you mean you're doing it *programmatically*? If so, please show us your code.

Comment: You only can do it programatically. It's just a simple scrollviewdidscroll and set the navbar frame based on the offset. That works fine and is not the issue. It's the black bar behind the navbar that needs to be transparent.